# Processing data in pgfplots: Elementwise multiplication?

Tags: pgfplots

I like to process data that I read in from a file within pgfplots. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstableread{chi_probe.dat}{\data}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={grid_omega_opt.dat}{0}] {xData} {\data}

\begin{axis}

\addplot[
black
] table [
x expr = \thisrowno{2}*1.054571726e-34,
y expr = \thisrowno{2}*\thisrowno{1}
] {\data};

\legend{probe,differential}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What I do is mutiplying the x values with \hbar. The y axis actually should show x*y, which is meant to be an elementwise mutiplication, means Y1=x1*y1, Y2=x2*y2, etc. where Y are the y axis values. To be more general: Is any function applied on a column (e.g. ^2, sqrt, etc.) performed element wise?

Comment: Yes, it is. Do you encounter difficulties with your expressions which makes you doubt it?

Comment: Yes. Not in that example but in the following: `sqrt(\thisrowno{0}^2+\thisrowno{1}^2)`. I just found why: It seems without the sqrt, there are negative values!!! How can that be?

Comment: That is an unfortunate expansion effect: if the current value of `\thisrowno{0}` is `-1`, the result of the expansion is `sqrt(-1^2 + ...)` which is `sqrt(-1 + ...)`. The solution is to surround any macro by round braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the expressions are applied element-wise.

Note that expressions which rely on values in macros (as in `\thisrowno{0}`) generally need to be surrounded by round braces if exponentials are applied, i.e. `sqrt((\thisrowno{0})^2)` instead of `sqrt(\thisrowno{0}^2)` .